# How to add members to distribution list?

Tags: vba, outlook

We have a distribution list available to everyone in our organization.

I am trying to access this list to add members.

My first task is to set a variable that points to this distribution list. I found this code:

```
Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI") 
Set myFolder = myNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts)  
Set myItem = myFolder.Items("Project Team")
```

The problem is this list does not exist in my default contact list folder. How do I find out the name of the folder in which it resides?

Or is there another way to code this so I would not need to know the folder name?

---

I figured out how to access this list through VBA:

```
Dim olEntry As Outlook.AddressEntry
Dim olDL As Outlook.ExchangeDistributionList
Dim i As Long
Set olEntry = Application.Session.GetGlobalAddressList.AddressEntries("XYZ")
Set olDL = olEntry.GetExchangeDistributionList
For i = 1 To olEntry.Members.Count
    Debug.Print olDL.Members.Item(i),     olEntry.Members.Item(i).GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress
Next i
```

This code prints each member in this distribution list.

Next step:

How do I add a member to this list?

I am able to add new members through Outlook directly, so I have the proper permissions.

Comment: To return the members of a distribution list in the GAL https://www.slipstick.com/developer/code-samples/use-vba-to-create-a-list-of-exchange-gal-members/ To update you likely have to use non-VBA methods. **Exchange Server Mailing Lists** https://www.slipstick.com/exchange/exchange-server-mailing-lists/  **Procedures for address lists in Exchange Server** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/email-addresses-and-address-books/address-lists/address-list-procedures?view=exchserver-2019

Answer (score 0):

The macros below should get you started.

The first macro, `ContactDtls`, identifies the default contacts folder and then lists the number of items in every contacts folder it can reach.  The output will be something like:

```
Store containing default contacts folder: xxxxxxxx
Name of default contacts folder: Contacts (This computer only)
Items in default contacts folders: 20
All accessible contacts folders:
xxxxxxxx\Contacts (This computer only)  Items: 20
yyyyy\Contacts  Items: 123
zzzzzzzzz\Contacts  Items: 24
```

"xxxxxxxx" is probably the name of the store holding your emails.  This may not be true, the stores holding default folders are not always what you would expect.  On my system, the default contacts folder is named "Contacts (This computer only)".  Your contacts folder may have a different name.

The lines under "All accessible contacts folders:" list every accessible store containing a folder with a name starting "Contacts".  Some will be empty and some will contain contacts. If you do not know which store is the one you want, you will have to experiment with the second macro, `DsplContactsInSelectedFolder`.

The important statement in this macro is:

```
Set FldrContacts = .Folders("StoreName").Folders("ContactsFolderName")
```

In the list of accessible contacts folders, "xxxxxxxx", "yyyyy" and "zzzzzzzzz" are the names of the stores.  Replace "StoreName" by the name of the store you think contains the contacts you want. Replace "ContactsFolderName" by the name of the contacts folder in that store.  So perhaps:

```
Set FldrContacts = .Folders("yyyyy").Folders("Contacts")
```

When you run this macro, you should see the contacts you wish to process.  In addition to confirming you have the correct store, this macro gives you a simple example of accessing the contacts within a contact folder.

```
Option Explicit
Sub ContactDtls()

  Dim InxFldrCrnt As Long
  Dim InxStoreCrnt As Long

  With Application.Session
    Debug.Print "Store containing default contacts folder: " & .GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts).Parent.Name
    Debug.Print "Name of default contacts folder: " & .GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts).Name
    Debug.Print "Items in default contacts folders: " & .GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts).Items.Count
    Debug.Print "All accessible contacts folders:"
    For InxStoreCrnt = 1 To .Folders.Count
      With .Folders(InxStoreCrnt)
        For InxFldrCrnt = 1 To .Folders.Count
          If LCase(Left$(.Folders(InxFldrCrnt).Name, 8)) = "contacts" Then
            Debug.Print .Name & "\" & .Folders(InxFldrCrnt).Name & "  Items: " & _
                        .Folders(InxFldrCrnt).Items.Count
            Exit For
          End If
        Next
      End With
    Next
  End With

End Sub
Sub DsplContactsInSelectedFolder()

  Dim FldrContacts As Outlook.Folder
  Dim InxC As Long

  With Application.Session
    Set FldrContacts = .Folders("StoreName").Folders("ContactsFolderName")
    For InxC = 1 To FldrContacts.Items.Count
      With FldrContacts.Items(InxC)
         Debug.Print .FullName & "  " & .Email1Address
      End With
    Next
  End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks!!  This definitely gets me pointed in the right direction.  The only question is that  the distribution list is not within one of the default contacts folders.  It is in a globally accessible folder.   How would I reference that in the VBA code?  Is there another method I can use besides GetDefaultFolder to find out what that is?

Comment: @DennisHancy.  The lines after "All accessible contacts folders:" list **every contacts folder** you can access.  One of those will be the default folder but the rest will not.   The lines are "StoreName\FolderName  Items: nn".  You should recognise the name of the store holding the globally accessible folder.  Note that my second macro accesses a contacts folder by name.  You can access any folder by name.